# Can't create folder inside Shared project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Can't create folder inside Shared project in Visual Studio 2017. On place context menu I see only "**New Filter**"

[image]

Is it in general possible  - create folder in this type project ?

Update 1: - I mean create folder not in **Folder view**...

Comment: Maybe you just need to enable `Show all files` item in `Solution Explorer` toolbar?

Comment: Yes - you are right !

Comment: Add your answer , please ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you just need to enable `Show all files` item in `Solution Explorer` toolbar?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Filters are logical groupings of files, that aren't reflected in the filesystem. Creating filters is the only option available when looking at the *solution* view. If you want to add a filesystem folder instead you have to toggle between *solution* and *folder* view of the *Solution Explorer*:
[image: Toggle solution and folder view]

Once in *folder* view, you can create a filesystem folder:
[image: Add folder menu entry]

Comment: This is not exactly what I want - @VTT give more exactly answer in comment.

Comment: @Alexander: This answers the question you asked. If you are looking for something else, you need to ask that.

Comment: It's not working, because you can't add any files to the folder from "Add existing.."

Answer (score 0):

In general "enable Show all files item in Solution Explorer toolbar" is good desigion, but if you reopen vs2017 you need everytime enable it. So best desigion - change your settings in *Tools- Options.. - VC++ Project Settings - Solution Explorer Mode* - to the **Show all files**

[image]